# How can I make my character move left, right, and jump without issues?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently trying to make a 2d platformer game on Unity. I wanted to make the character move left, right, and jump up by pressing the left, right, and up arrows respectively. But I seem to have problems. When I pressed right or left arrows, the character continues moving even though I am not touching them anymore. Also, I cannot jump right and left.

This is my code, the value of `JumpStrength` is 8, while the value for `Speed` is 5:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    public float JumpStrength;
    public float Speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) == true)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpStrength;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) == true)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.right * Speed;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) == true)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.left * Speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is that once you set the velocity, you never set it to `0` when `Key` is `Released`.

```cs
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) == true)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpStrength;
    }
    else
    {
        // set Y to 0, so that it doesn't continue upwards
        // X should stay as it was before (we don't want to modify)
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(myRigidbody.velocity.X, 0);
    }

    // Notice all the "else" that are added. That way, only one branch can be executed
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) == true)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.right * Speed;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) == true)
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.left * Speed;
    }
    else
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, myRigidbody.velocity.Y);
    }
}
```

---

Also that way we are recreating/the vector again and again, so to simplify the code you would want to do it only once:

```cs
void Update()
{
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    
    // If pressed, set velocity to 1 to up, 0 otherwise (default)
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) == true)
    {
        y = JumpStrength;
    }

    // If going right, set velocity to 1
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow) == true)
    {
        x = Speed;
    } // otherwise check if going left, set velocity to -1, 0 otherwise (default)
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) == true)
    {
        x = Speed * -1; // Opposite direction
    }

    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);

}
```

... And in the end, I'm not sure about exact format/type of the game, but you might instead just "add" the new Velocity to existing one, instead of replacing it completely. So the last line would change to:

```cs
// from this
myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(x, y);

// to this
myRigidbody.velocity += new Vector2(x, y);
```

Comment: When I tried your solution, the character could not move at all.

Comment: I think the solution is missing out something, anyways, thank you so much for the solution!

Comment: you might want to add the velocity to your existing velocity instead - I don't know how your game looks like and what you expect from the character, so I'm just following your code. Try this on last instead: `myRigidbody.velocity += new Vector2(x, y);`